# How to "switch" a vector field from $TM$ to $T^*M$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Then the metric provides musical isomorphism $\flat:TM\rightarrow T^*M$. Now, consider a vector field on $TM$, $X:TM\rightarrow TTM$; is there a way to induce an associated vector field $\tilde{X}:T^*M\rightarrow TT^*M$ through the musical isomorphism?

Comment: $\flat:TM\rightarrow T^*M$ is a diffeomorphism, so $\flat_* :T(TM)\rightarrow T(T^*M)$ is one choice.

Comment: Thank you. I would have a particular vector field I would like to "switch". It is the vector field that gives the Hamiltonian flow. $X(q,\dot{q}):=\dot{q}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}-\Gamma^j_{kl}\dot{q}^k\dot{q}^l\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}^j}$. How does $\tilde{X}$ becomes in this case? Thank you again.